# Best way to predict something?

Tags: word-usage

What is the best way to predict something? For example, yesterday I tried a new social network called NextDoor and I think it will be great. It is correct to say:

> I think that NextDoor will be great.
>
> I guess that NextDoor will be the next Facebook.

Is is correct or it is a better way to express a prediction?

Comment: Use "I think" to express your belief about a future event without expressing an opinion about the value of said event. Use "I guess" if you want to predict an event while expressing resignation toward or acceptance of said event.

Comment: There's also, "**I suppose**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of verbs used to express an opinion about future events: [*think, imagine, predict, believe, envision, foretell, suppose, guess, hope, expect, anticipate*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/predict), and various others.  It's too much for me to go into the exact definition of each of these and their individual nuance, so please consult a dictionary.

Meanwhile, some examples:

> I *expect* that John will come to my dinner party this evening.
>
> I *envision* a future where everyone will have clean water and abundant food.
>
> I *predict* that our country's team will win the next World Cup.